# Time converter from GMT to Local according to country

Tags: android

I am downloading some JSON data from a webservice. In this JSON I've got some Date/Time values. Everything in GMT. How can I parse this date string so the result Date object is in the current locale?

I am getting only Time   like 22:00, 03:30 in GMT time.
and i want it to display it according to country's time in format like 9:00 AM/PM.
and i am new to Android so i have used a method as shown below but it does not work properly.

private static String getLocalTime(int hr, int min) {
        String localTime = "";

```
    Calendar gmt = Calendar.getInstance();

    gmt.set(Calendar.HOUR, hr);
    gmt.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    gmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    Calendar local = Calendar.getInstance();
    local.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    local.setTime(gmt.getTime());

    int hour = local.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minutes = local.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    boolean am = local.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM;
    String str_hr = "";
    String str_min = "";
    String am_pm = "";

    if (hour < 10)
        str_hr = "0";
    if (minutes < 10)
        str_min = "0";
    if (am)
        am_pm = "PM";
    else
        am_pm = "AM";

    localTime = str_hr + hour + ":" + str_min + minutes + " " + am_pm;
```

return localTime;
    }

Comment: first you need to parse your JSON date using `SimpleDateFormatter`

Comment: show your JSON date/time format please ?

Comment: Please provide some code you are using and results you are getting to improve the question's quality

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your date in following format,

```
String date = "Wed, 04 Feb 15 08:38:32 GMT";
```

You can first parse it using `SimpleDateFormatter` with `Locale` set to `default`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss Z", Locale.getDefault());
```

([list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of `SimpleDateFormat`)

If you then convert it to `Date` object and print it, then it will show time in your locale.

```
Date d = formatDate.parse(date);
System.out.println(formatDate.format(d));
```

**Output**,

```
Wed, 04 Feb 15 01:38:32 +0500
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a `SimpleDateFormat` for your desired output.

Now use the following code to convert
`desired_sdf.format(yourDate.getTime()+TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset())`